# React-Redux connect isn't getting store from Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Im using Redux with React Native to manage state. I believe that I've successfully set up the store and Provider. I can use `store.getState()` and `store.dispatch(action())` from any component successfully, however, the `react-redux connect` function is not allowing me to access the store from child components. Can you find anything wrong with my code below?

Login.js - This child component I'm testing won't access redux store with react-redux connect.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import actions from '../../redux/actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // To test if this function fires, which it is not
  console.log('login state mapping through redux');
  return {
    state: state,
  };
};

const dispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    userRecieved: (user) => dispatch(actions.userRecieved(user)),
  };
};

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          credentials: {
            email: '',
            password: '',
          },
        };
    }

  componentDidMount(){
    // This will show whether redux is connected
    console.log(this.props.state);
    this.props.userRecieved('TEST USER');
  }

  render() {
    return ( <Text>{this.props.state}</Text> );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Login);
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import YEET from './src/YEET.js';
import store from './src/redux/stores/index';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <YEET />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

My Redux Files:

store.js

```
import { combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux';
import accountReducer from '../reducers/accountReducer';
import postReducer from '../reducers/postReducer';

const initialState = {};

const reducers = combineReducers({
    account: accountReducer,
    post: postReducer,
});

const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);

export default store;
```

actions.js

```
import constants from '../constants';
var userRecieved = user => ({
  type: constants.USER_RECIEVED,
  data: user,
});

export default {
  userRecieved,
};
```

accountReducer.js

```
import constants from '../constants';

var initialState = {
    user: {
        photos: [],
    },
};

export default (state = initialState, action ) => {
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
        switch (action.type) {
            case constants.USER_RECIEVED:
                const user = {
                    id: action.data.uid,
                    // photos: action.data,
                };
                console.log(action);
                newState.user = user;
                return newState;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

Comment: We can help more if you upload the full code to the expo
This is usually a slight typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, the only reason could be that you're importing the unconnected component.

When you import the `Login` component, make sure that you import the `default` export instead of the `named` export.

So, wherever you import the `Login` component, do it like this:

```js
import Login from 'your-login-component-location/Login'
```

instead of

```js
import { Login } from 'your-login-component-location/Login'
```

The second one is a named export, which will return the `Login` class directly.
The first one is the default export, which will return the `connected` component.